# `bazel query ./main.cpp --output=location` does not return `~/project/package/BUILD:lnum:column` format

Tags: bazel

In Bazel 4.2.2 I could do a "go-to-reference" on a source file to get the path of the corresponding `BUILD` file, along with the line and column numbers pointing to where the source file is referenced:

```
bazel query ./main.cpp --output=location
~/project/package/BUILD:124:8: source file //package:main.cpp
```

In Bazel 5.1.1 this command returns the path of the very same source file:

```
bazel query ./main.cpp --output=location
~/project/package/main.cpp:1:1: source file //package:main.cpp
```

How to get the old behavior back?

P.S. This [ticket](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/12322) requests the new behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is to use `--noincompatible_display_source_file_location`:

```
bazel query ./main.cpp --output=location --noincompatible_display_source_file_location
~/project/package/BUILD:124:8: source file //package:main.cpp
```